# What is a simple way to store mixed values as a key value pair in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to figure out a way to store mixed values as a key value pair.

What I have so far is a 2 level LinkedHashMap. The first level is my primary keys. Which are the names of the items. Each key is a LinkedHashMap too. This is where I am trying to work. In the second LinkedHashMap I need to be able to store mixed values. For example boolean, int, float.

Any ideas how to do so?

Also is there a better way to achieve my idea than nested LinkedHashMaps? To me it seemed like the best thing.

I don't really have any code, this is all scratch paper right now.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i´d create my own generic class that stores just one Value and use this as the value of the Map. But despite that it just looks like a weird design to store everthing in a single Map

Comment: @npinti I am trying to create a nested list of items and each item will have multiple attributes.

Comment: In that case doing what *Kevin Esche* and *Danyal Sandeelo*, that is, creating your custom class which will be used to store the attributes would seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `custom class` and have all the required data types there.

Declare the map as:

```
 Map<String,YourCustomClass> myDataMap = new HashMap<String,YourCustomClass> ();
```

You can even make it as `<String, Object>` to make it generic, you can perform casting later on based on your logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own class containing both the two parts of your key, thus define the `equals` and `hash` methods for that class and use its instances as keys of an `HashMap`, without the need of having two maps in cascade.